# Timer with confirm and cancel button

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

i'm  a noobs at sweet alert.
Is it possible to create a sweet alert prompt which has confirm button, cancel and timer.

The logic is if the alert not confirmed, timer automatically execute the same function with cancel. I have tried and stuck. even if the alert confirmed, the timer still counting and the the cancel function is called.

```
sweetAlert({
    title: 'Stay in fullscreen',
    text: "You will be logged out in 10 seconds or if you leave the fullscreen!",
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#ff0000',
    confirmButtonText: 'Go fullscreen!',
    cancelButtonText: 'Leave this page!',
    confirmButtonClass: 'btn btn-success',
    cancelButtonClass: 'btn btn-warning',
    closeOnConfirm: 'true',
    timer:'10000',
    buttonsStyling: false
},function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm) {
        return launchIntoFullscreen(document.documentElement) // timer still still counting
    } else {
        return Redirect() 
    }
}).then(function () {
    swal(
        window.alert('teest')
    )
}, function (dismiss) {
    // dismiss can be 'cancel', 'overlay',
    // 'close', and 'timer'
    if (dismiss === 'timer') {
        return Redirect()
    }
})
```

Comment: show what you have tried and stuck with in OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking the `isConfirm` argument for null should tell you if the callback was initialized by the timer finishing.

```
swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",
    text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",
    timer: 2000,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true
  }, 
  function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm === null || isConfirm == false)
      cancelFunction();
    else
      confirmFunction();
  }
);
```

As far as I could find, this behavior is not documented, but I believe this is the [relevant bit of the source](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/blob/34b612ce6231a1cc04919b3df398e6ed2bb9e9c1/dist/sweetalert-dev.js#L836)

Comment: so, ( isConfirm === null ) will ignore the timer when confirm button clicked

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. Could you clarify your desired behavior?

Comment: confirmed : confirm function
cancel : cancel function
time out : also cancel function

Comment: Then yes, just check `if (isConfirm === null)` and then call the desired cancel function. I'll update my snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
swal({
    title: "Auto close alert!",
    text: "I will close in 2 seconds.",
    timer: 2000,
    showConfirmButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true
  }, 
  function(isConfirm) {
    if (isConfirm === null || isConfirm == false)
      cancelFunction();
    else
      confirmFunction();
  }
);
```

the code above still execute cancelFunction();
i add a line before Confirmfunction.

```js
if (isConfirm !=null && isConfirm != false) {
   closeInSeconds = Number.MAX_VALUE/1000; // this line extends timer time
   document.documentElement);
}
else {
   Redirect();
}
```